# mod_rewrite to convert a URL path to a Query String

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod-rewrite to convert:

```
https://newbootstrap.com/quiz
```

to:

```
https://newbootstrap.com/index.php?url=quiz
```

This is my .htaccess:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options -Indexes

    AddType text/x-component .htc

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml

    <IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$ 
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text\.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image\.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.* 
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>

    #Запрет перехода с определенного сайта
    #<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} bannedurl1.com [NC,OR]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} bannedurl2.com [NC,OR]
    #RewriteRule .* - [F]
    #</ifModule>
```

Comment: I made a change to your question. Please check the language. Make sure, that my words mean the same as your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^quiz$ /index.php?url=quiz [L]`

Or if this is a generic rule for any request:

`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

A complete .htaccess file to achieve this end would be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```